# RDBMS vs NoSQL decision making

Tags: database-design, replication, nosql, rdbms

I am pretty novice when it comes to data store, and want to learn few tricks.

I want to know how to decide between RDBMS and a NoSQL store.

Lets take example of a system where data size is pretty big, say TBs. And we also need strong consistency, but also low latency.

For data size concern, NoSQL may be a good fit, but for consistency reason RDBMS type may seem good. But high consistency means poor latency.

Though some RDBMS also offer sharding for solving big data sizes, but latency is still an issue.

How do we wade thorugh all these pros and cons to arrive at a decision?

Additionally, any resources on this topic from begineer's POV may be a great help.

Comment: "*For data size concern, NoSQL may be a good fit*" - Size of data at rest has nothing to do with deciding between a NoSQL and SQL database solution. Both handle the same amounts of data (roughly speaking) just the same.

Comment: What data are you going to put into that DB?

Comment: Mostly structured data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between NoSQL and a traditional RDBMS?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-are-the-differences-between-nosql-and-a-traditional-rdbms)